# SerializedName vs. Custom GSON Deserializer for nested POJO

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a json string that I want to parse to a java object.

Json String:

```
"[{\"name\": \"favorite list\", \"books\": [
    {\"title\": \"bookTitle1\", \"description\": \"book description\"}, 
    {\"title\": \"bookTitle2\"}
]}]"
```

Java Classes:

```
public abstract class BookList {
  public abstract String name;
  public abstract List<Book> books;
}

public abstract class Book {
  public abstract String title;
  public abstract String description;
}
```

When deserializing the JSON string to java object, I want each of `book` object to have both `title` and `description` fields. If the `description` value is missing from the JSON string, I want the `title` value to be set to the `description` field too.

Desired Java Output:

```
[{name: "favorite list", books:[
   {"title": "bookTitle1", "description": "book description"},
   {"title": "bookTitle2", "description": "bookTitle2"}
]}]
```

I tried to use `@SerializedName` annotation to get `description` field populated with `title` field when `description` field is missing, but it didn't work. Is the only way to solve for this be to create a custom deserializer for `BookList`? What is the best way to create the deserializer for the nested `Book` object?

Comment: why don't you just put it in the code? `if (book.getDescription()==null) book.setDescription(book.getTitle())`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I reproduced it without using abstraction in class. You can make changes if you want. Alternatively, you can use Lombok to make the code more concise if you want. The online version is found [here](https://onecompiler.com/java/3z4qmbxz6)

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String json = "[\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"favorite list\",\n" +
            "    \"books\": [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"title\": \"bookTitle1\",\n" +
            "        \"description\": \"book description\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"title\": \"bookTitle2\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "]";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Book.class, new BookDeserializer())
            .create();
        BookList[] bookLists = gson.fromJson(json, BookList[].class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bookLists));

    }

    public static class BookList {
        private String name;
        private List<Book> books;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Book> getBooks() {
            return books;
        }

        public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
            this.books = books;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BookList{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", books=" + books +
                '}';
        }
    }

    public static class Book {
      private String title;
      private String description;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Book(String title, String description) {
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Book{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
        }
    }

    public static class BookDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Book> {

        @Override
        public Book deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
            String title = obj.get("title").getAsString();
            JsonElement descriptionElem = obj.get("description");
            String description = descriptionElem != null ? descriptionElem.getAsString() : title;
            return new Book(title, description);
        }

    }

}
```